# meaning of "reflect judgement"

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

I can't quite understand what does "reflects judgement" mean in here. is it equivalent to " Help judgement" ?

> Further, in the absence of failure data, bayesian models consider that
>   the model parameters have a prior distribution, **which reflects
>   judgement on the unknown data based on history** e.g. a prior version
>   and perhaps expert opinion about the software.

Comment: What is the source? I would write "which reflects on the judgement of unknown data based on history", though it may be a matter of style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for the passage you quoted, and am assuming that you got it from [this paper](http://www.jetir.org/papers/JETIR1609008.pdf). I would say that this use of "*reflects judgement*" is not a normal form encountered in English, and is possibly used only due to English not being the first language of the authors of the paper.

Based on my knowledge of Bayesian models, I think what the authors might be trying to say could more clearly be written as:

> ... Bayesian models consider that the model parameters have a prior
>   distribution, which **makes predictions about** the unknown data based
>   on history....

or alternatively:

> ... Bayesian models consider that the model parameters have a prior
>   distribution, which **derives assumptions about** the unknown data based
>   on history....

I am guessing that they meant to communicate something along the line of one of these things. In your own writing, I would not recommend using "reflects judgement" in the manner the authors did in that paper.